# rolling a Circular mesh plane

Tags: animation

ok, take 2.
I need a circular plane subdivided with parallel subdivisions. (My initial attempt I was hoping I could transform a rectangular plane somehow.)

The end result I need is going from a disc curled up into to tube, to the disc laying out flat.
I created some subdivisions manually on a circle by selecting 2 vertices and connecting with F.

I also managed to modify the circle with a curve modifier so now it rolls up in the spiral.

[image]

[image]

But, the two questions I have are these:

1. how do I give it a solid surface as automatically happens when you add a mesh plane. I need it to unroll smoothly, so hopefully I can use cloth modifiers and shading.
   1a) why is the mesh plane solid and the mesh circle is not?
2. I want to unroll the subdivided circle out from the spiral while the spiral remains in a fixed position. (I don't want the spiral to move. Everything I have found up to now moves the spiral--but I can work with that if it comes down to it.)

It doesn't really matter that the divisions are uneven, but it would be nice if they were.
I also have a picture I need to map to the surface of the circle.

Blender V2.81.16 on Windows

Thanks in advance.

*Edit: In object mode I can move the paper in and out of the spiral, and vice versa. But if I set a keyframe location for either object I can no longer move the disc, just the spiral.

Comment: Nothing is the default fill type of a circle.  Change to another option to fill on creation. Select 2 verts F creates an edge, 3 or more a face. The step where you created the edges, could instead  make faces.  (Add a plane loop cut, then too sphere would be another suggestion). Did you attempt  moving the disc instead of the spiral?

Comment: in object mode I can move the paper in and out of the spiral, and vice versa. But if I set a keyframe location for either object I can no longer move the disc, just the spiral.

I'll have a look and see if I can find the option to change to a different fill setting.

Thanks.

Comment: You can *grid fill* the circle, that would allow for better deformation.

Comment: I got it working. Had to hunt around for the option location for creating the circle.

Answer (score 0):

batFINGER had the answer I needed. Filling the circle also somehow resolved the animation problems I was having. I created a new circle just to play with the options, but I actually just filled the subdivided circle I already created.

Thanks!